# Comparing two growth curves (SPSS)

Tags: spss, growth-model

I conducted a study in which students filled out a questionnaire about their motivation at four different times during a semester. Motivation was split up in different types of motivation (as such, for each type of motivation I have 4 data points per person).

I analysed the data using a Linear Mixed Model procedure of SPSS. That way I got estimates of following growth curves:

- Intrinsic motivation
- Identified motivation
- Introjected motivation
- Exteral regulations
- Amotivation

All but external regulations (linear function) are best described as a quadric function. However, growth curves of intrinsic, identified and introjected motivation look very similar on a graph (see image below). Is there any (easy) way to test if these growth curves are still significantly different or if these curves are similar?

I already conducted a search online, but none of the responses seems to fit my particular case. Can anyone help?

[image]